# Wcf logging messagebody problem

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to log messages in WCF using the following code, but `Message Body` is not written properly; It's written as `>... stream ...</s:Body>`. It used to write complete message body before with the same code.

```
public class MMServiceMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
        request = buffer.CreateMessage();
        Helper.LogMessage("Received: " + buffer.CreateMessage().ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the message is being streamed rather than buffered so it is not all in memory. Have you considered using the built in message logging functionality in the diagnostics?

**Edit**

To Force the contents of the message you can use the code discussed [here](http://www.pvle.be/2009/03/messagetostring-returning-stream/)

Comment: but the same code was writing message body fine until last week. I did not change any code

Comment: There is no guarantee that ToString will show you the message body - has the size of the message potentially changed?

Comment: Richard Blewett - no Size hasn't changed

Comment: Sorry I did not implement properly before but this link you sent helped me. Thanks a lot Richard!!